# How do I get the type with a type string when the version has changed?

Tags: c#

I am saving a list of type strings to be instantiated dynamically.  Using reflection, how do I get the type with a type string when the version number has changed?

Example, I have a type string defined as:

> AcmeCorporation.BusinessObjects.Customer, AcmeCorporation.BusinessObjects, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dccbd7ce7d6a58c0

```
//This works fine
Type type = Type.GetType(typeString, false);
```

However when my assembly version changes to `2.0.0.1` the saved type string does not work because the version numbers are diferent.

Can I find the assembly by name and then find the type by name?

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the version, why include it in your type string? All parts except the first one are optional in the string passed to `Type.GetType`:

```
Type t = Type.GetType("AcmeCorporation.BusinessObjects.Customer, AcmeCorporation.BusinessObjects");
```

Comment: That worked like a charm.  So I can always hack off the ",Version" at the end?  Will that work in other cultures?  Will the Version be something different in German or Russian?